# .htaccess is not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have purchased host gator vps server with level1 and have to deploye my zend app on that 
but my rewrite rules are not working , i tried with simplest

```
RewriteRule ^test.html http://www.google.com [NC,L]
```

but had no luck

I have rewrite engine on in httpd.conf 
and also checked `AcssesFile .htaccess` set
here is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

I have raised tickets but they wont help me on level 1 package :) ... any suggestion or direction would be greatly helpful

Comment: Did you check if the "mod_rewrite" module of Apache Web server was loaded?

Comment: Ahh got the solution : I have not configured virtual host in httpd.conf all is working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh got the solution : I have not configured virtual host in httpd.conf all is working now –

Answer (score 1):

Have you allowed over-riding in your httpd.conf file?

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride All
```

If it is set to none then you cannot use htaccess files. Change it to All.